# How to tell vuefire's firestore to execute after "created" hook?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

I am using [vuefire](https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire) for my new Vue.js project. But there is a problem with initialization...

One of my data property need to be intialized via a method. To do this, I use the *created* hook of Vue.js. Actually I need the value of this property for my firestore request.

Problem is : **the firestore request seems to run before the created hook**.

How can I run my firestore requests after the created hook as been run ?

Thank !

```
data: function () {
  return {
    currentWeek: null
  }
},
firestore: function (currentWeek) {
  return {
    slots: db.collection('slots').where('start', '>=', this.currentWeek)
  }
},
created: function () {
  this.currentWeek = moment().startOf('week')
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can solve this issue with watch and binding :

```
data: function () {
  return {
    currentWeek: null,
    slots: []
  }
},
created: function () {
  this.currentWeek = moment().startOf('week')
},
watch: {
  currentWeek (currentWeek) {
    this.$bind('slots', db.collection('slots')
      .where('start', '>=', moment(currentWeek).toDate())
  }
}
```

I am pretty sure a better solution can be found...

Answer (score 1):

this is not the exact code but, basically you want to use the `$firestoreRefs` to make the query yourself inside of the `created` lifecycle method

```
data: function () {
  return {
    currentWeek: null,
    slots : []
  }
},
created: function () {
  this.currentWeek = moment().startOf('week')
  this.slots = this.$firestoreRefs['slots'].where('start', '>=', this.currentWeek)
},
```

Comment: Well, this solution seems to not work as this.$firestoreRefs.where do not return the results directly...
Also, $firestoreRefs['slots'] do not exists if slots is not defined in firestore configuration

Comment: you need to provide more code if you want a more complete answer, without a project i can only make assumptions... and I stated that this was nto the completed solution but intended to point you in the direction of using the refs that are defined to make the initial query

Comment: Yes exactly, sorry for not having provided enough code and thank you a lot for your answer.
I proposed a solution that seems to work, but I am pretty sure that your solution is more elegant. I only have to find how to get the result, because .where() does not return a promise...